# GitHub Copilot issue on PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, github-copilot

I've been using GitHub Copilot plugin on PyCharm IDE for a while now. However, I recently encountered an issue where the plugin keeps turning off whenever I start writing a new line of code. Oddly, my GitHub subscription is still active. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

- Update github copilot plugin.
- Reauthenticate github copilot.
- Reinstall the plugin.
- Update PyCharm.

Comment: I logged in and out, removed and installed it again, and updated the plug in and restarted the system, still the moment I start coding it turns off.

Comment: Updating PyCharm got it fixed. Thanks for the suggestions.